# Finding Serial plan from Plan cache

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, parallelism, plan-cache

My application goes slow sometimes and when i check the query plan plan for a particular operation,i see that serial pans got generated and gets stored in the plan cache and this is being taken for further execution.
So every time i query the plan cache and i see like 50+ plan(i search for particular view in the  query text to find out the queries) and to find the serial plan i have to open Query plan and see whether it is parallel or not.

```
SELECT 
OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid,st.dbid) AS ObjectName,cp.creation_time,
cp.execution_count AS ExecutionCount,cp.plan_handle,
st.TEXT AS QueryText,
qp.query_plan AS QueryPlan
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) AS qp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) AS st
--CROSS APPLY query_plan.nodes('/ShowPlanXML/BatchSequence/Batch/Statements/StmtSimple') AS qn(n)
where 
st.text like '%FormSearchModel%'
--AND qp.query_plan.exist('//PhysicalOp="Parallelism"') = 0
--AND n.query('.').exist('//RelOp[@PhysicalOp="Parallelism"]') = 1
order by creation_time desc
```

It tried using `query_plan.exist('//PhysicalOp="Parallelism"') = 0` to find the serial plan and it is not working.
How can i achieve this.?Any suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan' AS p )
SELECT      OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid, st.dbid) AS ObjectName,
            cp.creation_time,
            cp.execution_count AS ExecutionCount,
            cp.plan_handle,
            st.text AS QueryText,
            qp.query_plan AS QueryPlan
FROM        sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) AS qp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) AS st
WHERE       1 = 1
--AND st.text LIKE '%FormSearchModel%'
AND         qp.query_plan.exist('//p:RelOp/@Parallel[ .= 0]') = 1
ORDER BY    cp.creation_time DESC;
```

If you want to find plans where *all* operations are serial, you'd have to do something like this:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan' AS p ),
relop AS 
(
SELECT      OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid, st.dbid) AS ObjectName,
            cp.creation_time,
            cp.execution_count AS ExecutionCount,
            cp.plan_handle,
            st.text AS QueryText,
            qp.query_plan AS QueryPlan,
            qp.query_plan.value('count(//p:RelOp)', 'INT') AS total_relop,
            qp.query_plan.value('count(//p:RelOp/@Parallel[ .= 0])', 'INT') AS serial_relop
FROM        sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) AS qp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) AS st
WHERE  qp.query_plan.exist('//p:RelOp/@Parallel[ .= 0]') = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM relop
WHERE relop.total_relop = relop.serial_relop
```

Comment: Can i count(Parallel attribute) = 0 ,then that means serial ryt?I was thinking of a way to count all parallel attribute to tackle the issue.

Comment: @user9516827 I don't think that's a very good approach. Many parallel plans will have some serial operations at the very end. But if that suits your needs, go for it.

Comment: I understand,but i as a temporary solution,i have to filter out serial plans from the huge list of plans.Going through each plan to identify serial plan is a big task,that is why i am trying to find out ways to filter pure serial plans. Plans with zero parallel elements will give me the required result,but i am unable to put that logic in the query.